# How to create an empty slice of slices

Tags: zig

How do I construct `[]const []const u8` without using an allocator?

I can do

```
var slice: []const []const u8 = undefined;
slice.len = 0;
// use slice
```

But there surely must be a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
var foo: []const []const u8 = &.{};
```

I leave it to you to judge if this is better and by how much.

Comment: Oh, wow. It's so much better than `&[_][]u8 {}`.

Comment: This makes use of [Type Coercion: Tuples to Arrays](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#toc-Type-Coercion-Tuples-to-Arrays).