# How do I initialize a slice of slices in Zig?

Tags: zig

I'm trying to initialize a slice of slices of strings -- i.e. a `[][][]const u8`, but it doesn't seem to be possible:

```js
var x: [][][]const u8 = [][][]const u8{};
```

This the compiler to say: `error: type '[][][]const u8' does not support array initialization syntax`.

```js
var x: [][][]const u8 = .{};
```

This works with slices of one or two levels apparently, but not here: `error: expected type '[][][]const u8', found '@TypeOf(.{})`.

---

I wanted to know how to initialize it with some elements inside, but I can't even initialize an empty one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty slice can be [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474179/how-to-create-an-empty-slice-of-slices) created using the `&.{}` syntax. For example:

```
var x: [][][]const u8 = &.{};
```

But if you try to initialize it with elements inside, you'll get errors. You'll have to make the slices `const`, for example:

```
var y: []const []const u8 = &.{
    "hello",
    "world",
};

var z: []const []const []const u8 = &.{
    &.{
        "hello",
    },
    &.{
        "world",
    },
};
```

Or use an allocator:

```
var w: [][][]const u8 = try allocator.alloc([][]const u8, 10);
defer allocator.free(w);
// ...
```

Comment: So after allocating I just assign to positions in the slice? Like `w[0] = ...` (presumably I'll have to allocate and assign the sub-slices too)? (I did this and it worked, just asking if this is the more idiomatic approach.)

Comment: The idiomatic approach is to... use what's appropriate for the situation:
(a) If the data is known at compile time and won't change during execution, use `&.{ ... }`.
(b) If the data is only used in the function and had has a known and reasonable maximum size, use a buffer on the stack. E.g.
`var buffer: [128]u8 = undefined; const str = try std.fmt.bufPrintZ(&buffer, "...", .{ ... }); use_printed_string(str);`
(c) If none of this applies, then using an allocator is your last choice. But even then, you can use a custom allocator like `ArenaAllocator` for more control.